# How do I rotate an ad on a page loading the list of ads from an external file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, image-rotation

I'm trying to load a variable from a file using javascript.  I've found some examples but I can't seem to make it work and could really use some help on getting my syntax right.

Basically, I want to load a random ad image on a page, but I would like the list of ads to be pulled from a file.  Currently I'm loading the images using the following script which I found on the internet:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var picPaths = [
      '/images/ad-1.jpg',
      '/images/ad-2.jpg',
      '/images/ad-3.jpg',
      '/images/ad-4.jpg'
     ]
     var oPics = [];
     for(i=0; i < picPaths.length; i++){
      oPics[i] = new Image();
      oPics[i].src = picPaths[i];
     }
     curPic = Math.floor(Math.random()*oPics.length);
     window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById('imgRotator').src = oPics[curPic].src;
     }
    </script>
```

I have been trying to get the picPath variable value to load from a file (instead of stating it in the code).  I found some code here on stackoverflow and tried adjusted it to the following:

```
    var picPaths = new XMLHttpRequest();
    picPaths.open('GET', '/images/liveimages.inc');
    picPaths.send();
```

I also created the file /images/liveimages.inc which containts the following:

```
     '/images/ad-1.jpg',
     '/images/ad-2.jpg',
     '/images/ad-3.jpg',
     '/images/ad-4.jpg'
```

But, alas, it’s not working and I’m not programmer enough to fix it.  :-(  I'm thinking my syntax is off but my code could be off too since I am not a JavaScript guy.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks for taking the time to read (and respond) to my question!  :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the data file as JSON you can use AJAX/XMLHTTPRequest to fetch it, and `JSON.parse` (available in all modern browsers) to read it.

---

An easier way perhaps is just to have a script that contains just the data, like:

```
var picPaths = [
 '/images/ad-1.jpg',
 '/images/ad-2.jpg',
 '/images/ad-3.jpg',
 '/images/ad-4.jpg'
];
```

And then include your scripts in the correct order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="picpaths.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ad_script.js"></script>
```

ad_script.js will be able to access `picPaths`.

You could have some server-side script generate picpaths.js for you, for instance by looking at the contents of a folder or a database and pulling the ad info from that.

Comment: Fantastic!

I didn’t even think of breaking it up like that. I just loaded into the code and it worked like a champ!

I like your idea of generating the picpath.js with a script too since all the image files exist in one directory... I’ll have to look into that.  In the meantime the people that are loading the ads can edit the picpath.js file directly without having to get into the rest of the code.

Thanks so much for your help, it’s REALLY appreciated!  :-D